# Why is my KeyPressed method never called?

Tags: java

I am trying to write my first PacMan game. So I followed a guide and created a small game engine and now I am writing code in the PacMan.java file which includes the game engine as a package. The problem is, the guide instructs you to override the KeyPressed method, but when I do this NOTHING happens. The PacMan on the screen is supposed to change its direction according to what arrowkeys I press according to the KeyPressed() method but when I press the arrowkeys NOTHING happens. I can't control the little pacman through the arrowkeys even though I have the code for it!

I even put a simple System.out.println(); statement inside the KeyPressed() method to see if the KeyPressed() method is even ever actually called, but it is NEVER called it seems? "pressed the key" isn't being printed out when I press the arrowkeys and neither is the PacMan moving when I press them. Can anyone understand why my KeyPressed method won't be called when I press my arrowkeys?

My code:

```
package game.pacman;

import org.game.engine.Game;
import org.game.engine.GameApplication;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PacMan extends Game {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        GameApplication.start(new PacMan());

    }

    BufferedImage pacman;
    int frame;
    int dir;
    int x, y;
    final int STEP = 2;

    public PacMan(){
        title = "PacMan";
        frame = 0;
        dir = KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT;
        x = 300;
        y = 200;
        width = height = 400;

        try {
            pacman = ImageIO.read(new File("images/packman.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){

        System.out.println("pressed the key");
        dir = e.getKeyCode();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(){
        frame++;

        if (frame > 2){
            frame = 0;
        }
        switch (dir){
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                x -= STEP;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                x += STEP;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                y -= STEP;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                y += STEP;
        }
        if ( x < 0){
            x = 0;
        } else if (x > width-28-STEP){
            x = width-28-STEP;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        g.drawImage(pacman.getSubimage(frame*30,(dir-37)*30,28,28), x, y, null);
    }
}
```

Obviously it is supposed to override (through the package) a method KeyPressed inside a class Game.java inside the game engine which implements KeyListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener. Here is the whole code code for that class:

```
package org.game.engine;


import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public abstract class Game implements KeyListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{

    protected boolean over;
    protected int delay = 30;
    protected int width = 400;
    protected int height = 400;
    protected String title = "MyGame";


    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }
    public long getDelay(){
        return delay;
    }

    public int getWidth(){
        return width;
    }
    public int getHeight(){
        return height;
    }

    public void init(){}
    abstract public void update();
    abstract public void draw(Graphics2D g);

    public boolean isOver(){
        return over;
    }



    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }


    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    }


    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }


    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }


    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }


    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }


    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }


    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }


    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

    }


    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

    }
}
```

So as you can see the KeyPressed() method is just empty inside the class and this is how the guide instructs it to be. I am overriding it in the PacMan class (my main class). So why isn't either the arrow keys working, why isn't even the KeyPressed method being called at all when I run the program? Is something missing to call the KeyPressed() method?

Answer (score 1):

Though you implement the handlers in Game class and ovveride them in subclass, you haven't registered the handler to the element you want.

For ex, inside Game class,

```
something.onKeyPress(this) 

// where this is Game class which is of type KeyListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. Are you saying I should add "something.onKeyPress(this)" inside the KeyPressed method inside the Game class? Or what should I change to make it work?

Comment: @OfeliavanAnalhard On which element you want to detect the keypress ?

Comment: What does element mean here? Sorry for being such a beginner but I don't understand what you mean with "element"...

Answer (score 1):

you have to register component with `Key-Listener` for that do likewise,

If your component is JTextField then it should be likewise,

```
JTextField  typingArea = new JTextField(20);
typingArea.addKeyListener(this);
```

while press key inside, `typingArea - JTextField` it will called this method too,

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        displayInfo(e, "KEY PRESSED: ");
    }
```